# Unable to install stripe in Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, stripe

Using Magento 2.4.6 with PHP 8.2
When running  composer require stripe/stripe-payments I have no problem.
However when I run  sudo bin/magento setup:upgrade
I get

```
unable to apply data patch StripeIntegration\Payments\Setup\Patch\Data\Patch003InitialFees for module StripeIntegration_Payments. Original exception message: The "stripe_sub_enabled" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again.
```

I should mention my composer.lock

- Locking stripe/module-payments (3.4.1)
- Locking stripe/stripe-payments (3.4.0)
- Locking stripe/stripe-php (v7.128.0)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the product attribute **stripe_sub_enabled** doesn't exist. I'm not sure if this has been manually deleted or not, but it seems as though this should be created by **\StripeIntegration\Payments\Setup\Patch\Data\InitialInstall**.

```
   private function initSubscriptions($setup)
    {
        $groupName = 'Subscriptions by Stripe';

        $attributes = [
            'stripe_sub_enabled' => [
                'type'                  => 'int',
                'label'                 => 'Subscription Enabled',
                'input'                 => 'boolean',
                'source'                => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'sort_order'            => 100,
                'global'                => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group'                 => $groupName,
                'is_used_in_grid'       => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid'    => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'used_for_promo_rules'  => true,
                'required'              => false
            ],
            'stripe_sub_interval' => [
                'type'                  => 'varchar',
                'label'                 => 'Frequency',
                'input'                 => 'select',
                'source'                => 'StripeIntegration\Payments\Model\Adminhtml\Source\BillingInterval',
                'sort_order'            => 110,
                'global'                => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group'                 => $groupName,
                'is_used_in_grid'       => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid'    => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'used_for_promo_rules'  => true,
                'required'              => false
            ],
            'stripe_sub_interval_count' => [
                'type'                  => 'varchar',
                'label'                 => 'Repeat Every',
                'input'                 => 'text',
                'sort_order'            => 120,
                'global'                => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group'                 => $groupName,
                'is_used_in_grid'       => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid'    => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'used_for_promo_rules'  => true,
                'required'              => false
            ],
            'stripe_sub_trial'       => [
                'type'                  => 'int',
                'label'                 => 'Trial Days',
                'input'                 => 'text',
                'sort_order'            => 130,
                'global'                => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group'                 => $groupName,
                'is_used_in_grid'       => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid'    => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'used_for_promo_rules'  => true,
                'required'              => false
            ],
            'stripe_sub_initial_fee' => [
                'type'                  => 'decimal',
                'label'                 => 'Initial Fee',
                'input'                 => 'text',
                'sort_order'            => 140,
                'global'                => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group'                 => $groupName,
                'is_used_in_grid'       => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid'    => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'used_for_promo_rules'  => true,
                'required'              => false
            ]
        ];

        $categorySetup = $this->_categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        foreach ($attributes as $code => $params)
            $categorySetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $code, $params);

        $this->sortGroup($groupName, 11);
    }
```

The patch that's failing has a dependency on this, so shouldn't fail.
**StripeIntegration\Payments\Setup\Patch\Data**

```
public static function getDependencies()
{
    /**
     * This is dependency to another patch. Dependency should be applied first
     * One patch can have few dependencies
     * Patches do not have versions, so if in old approach with Install/Ugrade data scripts you used
     * versions, right now you need to point from patch with higher version to patch with lower version
     * But please, note, that some of your patches can be independent and can be installed in any sequence
     * So use dependencies only if this important for you
     */
    return [
        \StripeIntegration\Payments\Setup\Patch\Data\InitialInstall::class
    ];
}
```

If this is your local environment, it may be worth just removing all entries for this module from the patch_list table in the database, then try to re-run setup:upgrade. This should mean that the datapatch that creates this attribute is run first, which should prevent the error happening that we're seeing here.

Comment: Thanks I actually just deleted the patch. However I will try your method. thx